# Cannot create a local site on a IP (default.aspx not getting hit)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-8

I cannot get a default.aspx page to show on IIS.  I am running a windows server 2012 box. IIS 8. The site has a default.aspx page in its root directory. It is a application. The site is bound to a specific IP Address. When i hit that IP i do not get a default page. When i target the page `10.10.10.10/default.aspx` i get the following error

```
HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found

The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.



Most likely causes:
•The request matched a wildcard mime map. The request is mapped to the static file handler. If there were different pre-conditions, the request will map to a different handler.



Things you can try:
•If you want to serve this content as a static file, add an explicit MIME map.



Detailed Error Information:



Module
   StaticFileModule 

Notification
   ExecuteRequestHandler 

Handler
   StaticFile 

Error Code
   0x80070032 



Requested URL




       http://10.10.10.10/default.aspx 

Physical Path
   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testSite\default.aspx 

Logon Method
   Anonymous 

Logon User
   Anonymous 




More Information:
```

I am not sure what could be configured wrong. Does any have any recommendations?

Comment: `The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the **static file handler**.` Is ASP.Net installed in the box and configured for that application?

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net is not enabled by default on Server 2012. You need to use Add Roles and Features. On the features tab of the wizard, make sure the correct version of .Net is selected to be installed and that HTTP Activation is also selected.